# How to auto update based on data entered into entry fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Let me start by saying I am VERY new to coding. I have pieced together and made a bit of code that evaluates an equation based on the data entered into 3 Entry fields. I have it so that when I hit "Calculate" it evaluates the equation and gives me an answer. Is there a way to have it auto calculate so that I would not have to hit calculate after each set of entries? Ideally, the user would just tab, enter data, tab, enter data, tab, enter data, then use the answer given. They would then repeat the process by tabbing back to the initial entry field.

Below is a copy of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def show_entry_fields():
     a, b, c = float(e1.get()), float(e2.get()), float(e3.get())
     s = (a + b + c) / 2
     height = (sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) * 2) / b
     height = float(format(height, '.3f'))
     height_label['text'] = str(height)
     side =(sqrt ((a ** 2) - (height ** 2)))
     side = float(format(side, '.3f'))
     side_label['text'] = str(side)

master = Tk()
master.attributes("-topmost", True)

Label(master, text="Measurement from nearest to 0+00").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Distance between points on Station Line").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e2 = Entry(master)
e2.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Measurement from farthest from 0+00").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e3 = Entry(master)
e3.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(master, text="Offset from station line").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
height_label = Label(master, text="")
height_label.grid(row=8, column=1)

Label(master, text="Feet from Measurement nearest to 0+00").grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
side_label = Label(master, text="")
side_label.grid(row=9, column=1)

Button(master, text='Calculate', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=10, column=0, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple ways to do it, but since the math performed is simple enough, I would suggest to use `root.after` to calculate your result. Basically it will try to calculate every 0.1 sec and displays the result if there is no error caught.

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def show_entry_fields():
    try:
        a, b, c = float(e1.get()), float(e2.get()), float(e3.get())
        s = (a + b + c) / 2
        height = (sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) * 2) / b
        height = float(format(height, '.3f'))
        height_label['text'] = str(height)
        side = (sqrt((a ** 2) - (height ** 2)))
        side = float(format(side, '.3f'))
        side_label['text'] = str(side)
    except ValueError: #catch empty field or invalid input error
        pass
    master.after(100, show_entry_fields)

...

master.after(100,show_entry_fields) # add this
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed that portion for me. I did come across one more question, if you are able. For my output, I currently have it set at 3 decimals. I would like to change the format to something like this (MS Office style):  Old Format: 150.55, New Format: 1+50.55. So would like it to separate at the 100's spot with a + symbol.